# how to fix 400 bad request error in HTTP response in angular2 and ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am getting success response from server but not getting error response.I don't know how to handdle 400-bad request from server.

Comment: Chain a .catch((error => console.log(error)); method on your http call.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Sure. I got result when response is success,but when response is 400:bad request then I do not get any error result.

Comment: Well,catch is not in angular2.It gives error for that code.. @JoeriShoeby

Comment: this.http.post(BACKEND_URL,JSON.stringify({"user_id":user_id,"token":token}),
  {headers:headers}).map((res:Response) => {
             let DebitCard = res.json();                   
                return DebitCard;
             }).catch(this.handleError);
   private handleError(error:any) {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error._body);
       return Observable.throw(error);

    }

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you handle it like this? (Just an example)

```
this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=10').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    this.posts = data.data.children;
}, err => {
    console.log("Not quite right");
});
```

You can also resolve reject the above in a promise

Answer (score 0):

let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, APPLICATION_JSON);

```
  return this.http.post(BACKEND_URL,JSON.stringify({mobile_no:mobile_no,email:email,otp:otp}),{headers:headers}).map((res:Response) => {

            let DebitCard = res.json();                   
           alert(JSON.stringify(DebitCard));
             if (res) {
                if (res.status === 201) {
                    return [{ status: res.status, json: res }]
                }

            }

        }).catch((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 500) {
                return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
            }
            else if (error.status === 400) {
                return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
            }

        });
```